# What is the counterpart to the GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl() Win32 API function?

Tags: c, winapi, acl

The [`GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446638.aspx) Win32 API function allows to retrieve the explicit entries of a file ACL. But when I change some entries, convert the result into a new ACL using [`SetEntriesInAcl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379576.aspx) and finally apply the ACL back to the file with [`SetSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588.aspx) all inherited entries seem to be lost and only the (changed) explicit entries are left.

Is there a counterpart function "SetExplicitEntriesInAcl" that only replaces the explicit entries within an ACL structure and keeps the inherited entries intact?

**Edit1: Code Sample**

I'm using code similar to the following lines for ACL update:

```
int RemoveAclAccessRights( HANDLE hFile, PSID SidPtr,
   DWORD AccessRights, ACCESS_MODE AccessMode )
{
   PACL OldAcl = NULL, NewAcl = NULL;
   PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecDesc = NULL;
   PEXPLICIT_ACCESS EntryList = NULL, EntryItem;
   ULONG EntryCount, EntryIndex;
   int r;

   // Get a pointer to the existing DACL
   r = GetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
      NULL, NULL, &OldAcl, NULL, &SecDesc);
   if ( r != ERROR_SUCCESS )
      goto _CleanUp;

   r = GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl(OldAcl, &EntryCount, &EntryItem);
   if ( r != ERROR_SUCCESS )
      goto _CleanUp;

   EntryList = EntryItem;
   EntryIndex = 0;
   while ( EntryIndex < EntryCount ) {
      // ... update access entry ...
      EntryIndex++;
      EntryItem++;
   }

   // Create a new ACL from the explicit entries of the existing DACL
   r = SetEntriesInAcl(EntryCount, EntryList, NULL, &NewAcl);
   if ( r != ERROR_SUCCESS )
      goto _CleanUp;

   // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL
   r = SetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
      NULL, NULL, NewAcl, NULL);

   _CleanUp:
   LocalFree(NewAcl);
   LocalFree(EntryList);
   LocalFree(SecDesc);

   return r;
}
```

**Edit2: ACLs of the file and parent directory**

Output of `icacls` on the file:

```
> icacls TestAcl01.txt
TestAcl01.txt VORDEFINIERT\Gäste:(R)
              VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren:(I)(F)
              NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
              NT-AUTORITÄT\Authentifizierte Benutzer:(I)(M)
              VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer:(I)(RX)
```

Output of `icacls` on the parent directory:

```
> icacls .
. VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren:(I)(F)
  VORDEFINIERT\Administratoren:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
  NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
  NT-AUTORITÄT\Authentifizierte Benutzer:(I)(M)
  NT-AUTORITÄT\Authentifizierte Benutzer:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
  VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer:(I)(RX)
  VORDEFINIERT\Benutzer:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
```

The file has one explicit entry which is "VORDEFINIERT\Gäste:(R)" (SID "S-1-5-32-546"). The other entries are inherited from the parent directory.

In the while loop above I am trying to delete the explicit entry if it matches the SID using code like

```
if ( (EntryItem->Trustee.TrusteeForm == TRUSTEE_IS_SID) && EqualSid(EntryItem->Trustee.ptstrName, SidPtr) ) {
   if ( EntryIndex < (EntryCount-1) )
      MoveMemory(&EntryList[EntryIndex], &EntryList[EntryIndex+1], (EntryCount-EntryIndex-1)*sizeof(EntryList[0]));
   EntryCount--;
   continue;
}
```

Comment: There is no such function because the order of ACEs is significant, and the system cannot guess what order you want the existing inherited ACEs to occur in, relative to the explicit entries you are setting. You need to specify all the ACEs so that the ordering is known.

Comment: Raymond's observation is technically correct (the best kind!) but may be misleading in this scenario.  By default, SetSecurityInfo will add inherited ACEs from the parent to the ACL you specify (using the preferred order) but if the file has been moved that might not be the same as the inherited ACEs that it had originally.

Comment: ... so you need to check that the parent directory has the inheritable ACEs you're expecting to be applied to the file, and that you're not specifying the PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION flag.  If that still doesn't work, please show your code, because it works perfectly for me.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: In my tests inherited ACEs were only added by `SetSecurityInfo` when working on directories, not when working on files.

Comment: Have you checked that the permissions in question are marked (OI) as well as (CI) on the parent directory?

Comment: Yes, `cacls .` shows them as "(OI)(CI)". Also when I run `icacls MyTestFile.txt /reset` on the test file the inherited ACEs are restored.

Comment: Your code looks identical to mine, which works perfectly for me.  The only possibilities I can think of: (1) there's something breaking things in the elided part of the code - does it work properly if you don't modify the array of explicit entries?  (2) You've opened the file with insufficient access rights.  (3) There's something about the specific permissions you're dealing with that is making it behave differently.  Can you post the output of `icacls` for both the parent directory and the file you're working on?  (4) What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: (1) Yes. (2) I opened the file handle with `GENERIC_READ | WRITE_DAC`. (3) See updated question above. (4) Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the information in the latest edit, I can now replicate your problem.  It only occurs in the case when you are removing all of the explicit entries from the DACL.

It turns out there's a nasty (and undocumented, so far as I can see) catch in [SetEntriesInAcl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379576(v=vs.85).aspx): if you pass it a zero-length array, it silently returns `NULL` as the new ACL rather than returning an empty ACL as you might reasonably expect.

The documentation for [SetSecurityInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588(v=vs.85).aspx) explains what happens in this case:

> If the value of the SecurityInfo parameter includes the DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION flag and the value of this parameter is set to NULL, full access to the object is granted to everyone.

That implicitly removes the inherited permissions (which are redundant anyway).

One way to fix the problem:

```
ACL empty_acl;
if (!InitializeAcl(&empty_acl, sizeof(empty_acl), ACL_REVISION)) 
    goto _CleanUp;

// Create a new ACL from the explicit entries of the existing DACL
r = SetEntriesInAcl(EntryCount, EntryList, &empty_acl, &NewAcl);
if ( r != ERROR_SUCCESS )
    goto _CleanUp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work but uses `GetAclInformation` and `GetAce` instead of `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` which requires pointer type checking and is thus somehow less convenient:

```
int UpdateAclAccessRights( HANDLE hFile, PSID SidPtr,
   DWORD AccessRights, ACCESS_MODE AccessMode )
{
   PACL DiscAcl = NULL;
   PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR SecDesc = NULL;
   ACL_SIZE_INFORMATION AclSizeInfo;
   PACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE AceItem;
   int AceIndex;
   int r;

   // Get a pointer to the existing DACL
   r = GetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
      NULL, NULL, &DiscAcl, NULL, &SecDesc);
   if ( r != ERROR_SUCCESS )
      goto _CleanUp;

   ZeroMemory(&AclSizeInfo, sizeof(AclSizeInfo));
   if (!GetAclInformation(DiscAcl, &AclSizeInfo, sizeof(AclSizeInfo), AclSizeInformation))
      goto _CleanUp;
   for (AceIndex = AclSizeInfo.AceCount-1; AceIndex >= 0; AceIndex--) {
      if (!GetAce(DiscAcl, AceIndex, &((void*)AceItem)))
         continue;
      if ( (AceItem->Header.AceType != ACCESS_ALLOWED_ACE_TYPE) &&
           (AceItem->Header.AceType != ACCESS_DENIED_ACE_TYPE) )
         continue;  // entry pointer structure does not match AceItem
      if ( (AceItem->Header.AceFlags && INHERITED_ACE) > 0 )
         continue;  // not an explicit entry

      // ... update/delete access entry in case it matches SidPtr ...
   }

   // Attach updated ACL to the file object
   r = SetSecurityInfo(hFile, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
      NULL, NULL, DiscAcl, NULL);

   _CleanUp:
   LocalFree(SecDesc);

   return r;
}
```